# No active package dartdoc Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to generated the documentation of my flutter app and the `dartdoc` command is not working as expected.

I have tried :

```
flutter pub global deactivate dartdoc 
flutter pub global activate dartdoc
```

The output is :

```
Resolving dependencies...
+ _fe_analyzer_shared 31.0.0
+ analyzer 2.8.0
+ args 2.3.0
+ async 2.8.2
+ charcode 1.3.1
+ cli_util 0.3.5
+ collection 1.15.0
+ convert 3.0.1
+ crypto 3.0.1
+ csslib 0.17.1
+ dartdoc 4.1.0
+ file 6.1.2
+ glob 2.0.2
+ html 0.15.0
+ logging 1.0.2
+ markdown 4.0.1
+ meta 1.7.0
+ package_config 2.0.2
+ path 1.8.0
+ pub_semver 2.1.0
+ source_span 1.8.1
+ string_scanner 1.1.0
+ term_glyph 1.2.0
+ typed_data 1.3.0
+ watcher 1.0.1
+ yaml 3.1.0
Installed executable dartdoc.
Warning: Executable "dartdoc" runs "bin/dartdoc.dart", which was not found in dartdoc.
Warning: Pub installs executables into $HOME/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):

  export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"

Activated dartdoc 4.1.0.
```

I have also added to my `PATH` the export suggested.

Now when i run the `dartdoc` command in my flutter app root directory , here is the output :

```
No active package dartdoc.
```

I have also tried to do a `flutter pub cache repair` but it didn't help.

What else can i do to make it work please ?

**Note** : It was working before i upgrade to `flutter 2.8`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also experienced this problem. In my case, I managed to solve it running:

```
dart pub global activate dartdoc
```

Instead of:

```
flutter pub global activate dartdoc
```